# Subtraction between two dates in different lines SQL ACCESS

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, diff

I'm trying to find the difference between two dates that are in different columns and rows.

In this command I make a difference on the same line:

```
SELECT 
   FACTRY.finish_datetime, 
   FACTRY.start_datetime, 
   DateDiff("n",[finish_datetime],[start_datetime]) AS date_diff
FROM FACTRY
WHERE (((FACTRY.job_number)='30'));
```

***The output:***

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|   start_date_time   |  finish_date_time   | date_diff |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| 17/08/2016 20:24:00 | 17/08/2016 20:25:00 |        -1 |
| 17/08/2016 20:25:00 | 17/08/2016 21:00:00 |       -35 |
| 17/08/2016 21:00:00 | 17/08/2016 21:01:00 |        -1 |
| 17/08/2016 21:01:00 | 17/08/2016 21:02:00 |        -1 |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

In Oracle the following SCRIPT works.

```
SELECT 
   start_date, 
   finish_date, 
   LEAD(finish_date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY finish_date) AS NextFinish 
FROM FACTRY 
WHERE job_number = 30;
```

But as in ACCESS these functions are not available anyone has any idea how to do?

Comment: it would be better if you can provide the original table with dummy data

Comment: Please don't add a huge chunck of HTML to share a table. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359195/7296893